# What is a type of record in Salesforce and in which use cases would you use them?

Tags: salesforce

What is a type of record in Salesforce and in which use cases would you use them?
Pleas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean `Record types`?

Record types helps you to configure different business processes, assign page layouts, and pick-list values. One Object can have different page layouts based on certain criteria. Simply you can control, which page layouts users see when viewing records, based on their user profile.

Some helpful references:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kCPKIA2

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/customize-a-salesforce-object/create-record-types

[Video Turorial - What is record types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6-VUULklPE)